# Embed an OAC report into Apex, header text align

Tags: oracle-apex, apex

I'm embedding an Oracle OAC report into APEX and I have it working but the headers in the OAC report are right justified where in the orginal OAC report they are left justified.

Original NSAW OAC Report - (headers are left justified)
[image]

Embedded OAC report in APEX - (headers are right justified)
[image]